# How to reset countdown in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm make some apps that can resend some otp when I tap "Resend". I'm trying to refresh state but it seems didn't work. Can someone help with how to reset that countdown timer?

[Dartpad Code](https://dartpad.dev/46b0be98804e6547c2774cec3f448462)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `function`

first you need to change your `restartTimer` to this

```
   void restartTimer() {
    setState(() {
      _controller.reset();
       _controller.forward();
    });
  }
```

then change the widget that use `Countdown` to this

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Countdown(
            restartTimer:restartTimer, // send the function
            animation: StepTween(
              begin: 1 * 60,
              end: 0,
            ).animate(_controller),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

After that you need to `receive` the function

```
class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({Key key, this.animation,this.restartTimer}) : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;
  final Function restartTimer;
   ....
```

then inside the `Countdown` change the `OnTap` to this

```
 onTap: () {
              this.restartTimer();
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
void restartTimer() {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    startTimer();
  }
```